# Click the Text in a Div and Type to change It

Tags: html, css, text

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="div1" id ="div1" onclick="onStepClicked()" style ="text-align:center">Step 1</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.div1 {
        width: 300px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid blue;
        box-sizing: border-box;
```

I'm trying to do something like Google does and when you click the text it allows you to edit it.  I don't know if there is something in css or in the Div itself for me to be able to do this.

Comment: What do you  mean "like Google does"?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a `<input type="text"/>` ? It's possible for a `<div>` to behave like an input with `contenteditable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `contenteditable` to edit make the `text` or `div editable`.

**HTML:**

```html
<div contenteditable="true">This is an editable text.</div>
```

[Contenteditable](http://html5doctor.com/the-contenteditable-attribute/)

Answer (score 1):

you can add `contenteditable="true"` attribute to your div.

Reference: http://html5doctor.com/the-contenteditable-attribute/

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use an input element like so?

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="type some text here"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you should contenteditable attribute which is one of cool html5 features

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp

This is a paragraph. It is editable. Try to change this text.